# Parsing a caffe prototxt file?

Tags: import, undocumented, neural-networks

Caffe has its own visualization tools, for instance you and draw all the layers in a network easily like so:
[image]

But I wanted to analyze a network structure myself in mathematica, so I started to write a prototxt importer, then I saw this:

> `` MachineLearning`CaffeImporter` ``

```
In[38]:= Names["MachineLearning`BuiltIn`PackagePrivate`*"]

Out[38]= {"MachineLearning`BuiltIn`PackagePrivate`file", \
"MachineLearning`BuiltIn`PackagePrivate`loadPaclet", \
"MachineLearning`BuiltIn`PackagePrivate`name", \
"MachineLearning`BuiltIn`PackagePrivate`name$", \
"MachineLearning`BuiltIn`PackagePrivate`p", \
"MachineLearning`BuiltIn`PackagePrivate`pacletname", \
"MachineLearning`BuiltIn`PackagePrivate`p$", \
"MachineLearning`BuiltIn`PackagePrivate`result", \
"MachineLearning`BuiltIn`PackagePrivate`result$", \
"MachineLearning`BuiltIn`PackagePrivate`tmp", \
"MachineLearning`BuiltIn`PackagePrivate`tmp$"}
```

So I wondered, is there functionality already in mma to do this?

Comment: Is there anything in the [CaffeLink package](https://github.com/Seilim/CaffeLink) that helps with importing Caffe files into MMA?

Comment: Not really, it seems like it's only for linking...

Comment: I think maybe you can first convert caffe model into mxnet model and then use `ImportMXNetModel` to import that.

Comment: I didn't think there's no robust way to do that @xslittlegrass

Answer (score 4):

It seems that the caffe prototxt file can be imported into Mathematica through the MXNet converter.

We first convert the caffe network definition files into MXNet files using the [caffe to MXNet converter](https://github.com/dmlc/mxnet/tree/master/tools/caffe_converter)

```
python convert_model.py VGG_ILSVRC_16_layers_deploy.prototxt VGG_ILSVRC_16_layers.caffemodel vgg16
```

Then we can load the MXNet files using `ImportMXNetModel`

```
Needs["MXNetLink`"]
ImportMXNetModel["vgg16-symbol.json","vgg16-0001.params"]
```

[image]

Here is the original caffe network visualized in [netscope](http://ethereon.github.io/netscope/quickstart.html).

[image]